# Site Navigation Setting lost in sharepoint 2013

Tags: navigation, site-settings

I wanted to add some links to my top navigation bar, so I went to site setting but in site navigation setting I didn't see any box for my links.
I have no idea what happened

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to your site's `Site Settings`->`Navigation` (`/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx`). Your top navigation can be configured here as the *Global Navigation*.

Assuming your site is the root of your site collection, select the *Global Navigation* as `Structural Navigation: Display the navigation items below the current site`. Below appears the configuration of *Structural Navigation*. Here you can hide the default shown links and add your own links by using *Add Link...* option.

Edit:

[image: Settings at AreaNavigationSettings.aspx]

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't get the main point of your answer    what should I exactly do? I have another share point 2013 web application on the same server and in that web app I can see this box (site navigation box) but in current web app I can't!

Comment: I didn't mention Site Navigation box anywhere :) Try to navigate to your `http://sitecollection.com/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx` (change the sitecollection.com to match your site collection's URL). Here you can configure the settings I mentioned.

Comment: I'm so sorry dear moe, you mean in AreaNavigationSettings.aspx there is some kind of for example property for site collection?

Comment: What do you mean by `property for site collection`? By your question I've understood your requirement is the following: You need to add links to your *Top navigation bar* which is the horizontal navigation menu. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No, I think I asked my question in wrong way :( in middle of AreaNavigationSettings.aspx page we should have a box for add or edit links and as I said in another web application on the same page I have this box but in my current web app this box has been lost

Comment: See my updated answer above. By these settings you should have the 'box' available.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work

Comment: Is there any required feature for site navigation setting?

Comment: Make sure you have activated `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure` from Site collection features and `SharePoint Server Publishing` from site features.

Comment: They were activated and I deactivate them and activate again but nothing especial happened to AreaNavigationSettings.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**To set link in Top navigation bar follow these steps:**

1) Click on Settings - Site Settings.

2) Under Look and Feel, click on Top link bar

3) Click on New Navigation Link

4) Type in the Web address to which you want the new link to point, type the description of the link and then click on OK.

Comment: Thank you But I Know that, the box which for add link or heading has been lost (the box in middle of page AreaNavigationSettings.aspx